# How to use loop extract index num to columns will overwrite?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, matplotlib

I want to let index number can be separate to `column[year]` and `column[month]`.

```
for i in range(len(df_tmp.index)):
    yy=str(df_tmp.index[i])[0:4]
    mm=str(df_tmp.index[i])[-2:]    
    df_tmp['year']=yy
    print(df_tmp['year'])
    i=i+1
```

But now the output is `columns[year]` be overwritten by the end of index.
and I don't know how to solve it.

[trace the wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x9AD.png)

[the output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov134.png)

Comment: What is the script that you're using to plot the result displayed in `the output result`'s image? It's not clear to me how you are using `df_tmp` variable to plot the year. Shouldn't it be a list?

Comment: I found the df what i want and post online,txs for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this sample code:

```
I = ['2111','2112','2201','2202']
df = pd.DataFrame( [3,1,2,5], index=I, columns=['variable'])
df['year'] = df.index.str[:2]
df['month'] = df.index.str[2:]

    variable    year    month
2111    3       21      11
2112    1       21      12
2201    2       22      01
2202    5       22      02
```

Comment: Thanks，i try it and tune a little datatype,finally succes the target.

df_tmp.index = df_tmp.index.astype(str) 
#add here to change data type#

df_tmp['year'] =df_tmp.index.str[:4]
df_tmp['month'] =df_tmp.index.str[-2:]

df_tmp